# R AOV will not do the interaction between two variables

Tags: r, anova, interaction, manova

I have in the past had R perform aov's with interaction between two varbles, however I am unable to get it to do so now.

Code:

```
x.aov <- aov(thesis_temp$`Transformed Time to Metamorphosis` ~ thesis_temp$Sex + thesis_temp$Mature + thesis_temp$Sex * thesis_temp$Mature)
```

Output:

```
                   Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
thesis_temp$Sex     1 0.000332 0.0003323   1.370 0.2452  
thesis_temp$Mature  1 0.000801 0.0008005   3.301 0.0729 .
Residuals          82 0.019886 0.0002425
```

I want it to also include a Sex x Mature interaction, but it will not produce this. Any suggestions of how to get R to also do the interaction analysis?

Comment: Could you share a part of your data with `dput(head(thesis_temp))`?

Comment: Here you go.

Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), 

Mature = c("N", "N", 
"N", "Y", "N", "N"))

`Transformed Time to Metamorphosis` = c(0.032258064516129, 
0.0357142857142857, 0.0384615384615385, 0.0555555555555556, 0.0526315789473684, 
0.0357142857142857),